# Linq linq-to-entities add join if condition is met

Tags: linq, join, linq-to-entities

I am quite new to c# and EF, and i could not find an answer for the following question, forgive me should i have overlooked one.

I want to join a "main query" query1 with several "optional querys" which go to different tables in the same model, how am i supposed to achieve that?

If i try to use the Join() method, it works as long as i do this:

```
var query = query1.Join(query2 [...]);
```

but when trying something like

```
query = query1;

if (condition_is_met)
{
    query = query.Join(query2 [...]);
}
```

i receive an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<someentity>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can i avoid this error, and/or is there actually a way to add joins if a condition is met?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the (i fear dumb) question.

Comment: The code you posted would compile but the `Join()` wouldn't do anything. Did you mean `query = query.Join(…)`?

Comment: oops, of course that, thank you ... i am a little tired ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally add to your query, but you need to understand that once your query is typed, you cannot change its type to something else. Your problem is that one of your queries types to an anonymous type, and another types to an entity, and that is inconsistent.

For an example that works, see:

```
var query = context.Foos.AsQueryable();

if (DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0)
{
    query = query.Join(context.Bars, f => f.BarId, b => b.Id, (f, b) => new { f, b }).Select(item => item.f);
}
else 
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id);
}
```

The reason this works is that the initial declaration is an `IQueryable<Foo>`, and each of the resulting queries (either the join or the ordered version) is still an `IQueryable<Foo>`.

If you need to project your query result to anonymous type, I recommend saving that for a later step (a query of your constructed query). Construct all of your joins, your filtering, your orders, etc., then finally pull out your anonymous type. As long as your type is the same regardless of the other logic you are including, you will be able to build upon your single query.

However, if the logic affects the shape of the data you actually retrieve, then that's where you're out of luck, you will need go another direction.

Comment: thanks for this answer, sheds quit sime light on how it works to me!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the result of the `Join()` is a type, that is different from the type of the original query. How should the code after the condition treat the variable? It could contain one of two different types. So, doing it like this is simply not possible.